# How do I make my style in core.css override style coming from scaffolding.less or any other css src in a mean.js application?

Tags: css, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack, mean.io

I am building an application using the mean.js framework. 
I am adding styles to core.css file in the modules/core/css in the public folder.
But when I do an inspect element on the page I see the styles being overridden by a styles coming from the files like scaffolding.less in the lib\bootstrap\css\less\scaffolding.less, etc.

If not core.css where should I add my style class to make them reflect on my html elements?

What is the ideal way to add style to pages in a mean.js application?

Comment: @jantimon : Thanks using important worked

Comment: You could also give https://github.com/jantimon/css-exclude/ a try